# How to delete a specific message by ID using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to delete a message using it's ID. I am using discord.py.

**Logic Flow**

> User sends command. example: !message hi
>   Bot deletes "!message hi" using User's message ID
>   Bot says "hi"

I have figured out how to get it to copy my messages, but I am having difficulty getting it to delete them. I didn't want to say that it deletes the message before it's one otherwise on busy servers it might not work. I wanted to get the command message's ID then delete it using it's ID.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

---

#### Updated for discord.py v1.2+

You should use the [`TextChannel.fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message) function.

```
msg = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
await msg.delete()
```

---

#### Original answer (no longer works):

To answer the question: To delete a message by ID, you must either fetch the message object (preferred) or go through `client.http` (not-preferred)

#### First option: Finding the message.

You can use the [`Client.get_message`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message) function

```
msg = await client.get_message(channel, message_id)
```

Alternately, your specific use case seems to just be deleting the message that was sent, so you could just use the message supplied by `on_message(msg)`
After you have the message, you can do:

```
await client.delete_message(msg)
```

---

#### Second option: Using client.http

Assuming you know the channel's ID, you can simply call

```
await client.http.delete_message(channel_id, message_id)
```

This method while useful for deleting arbitrary messages in arbitrary places shouldn't be used if getting the message is feasably an option.

Comment: Forgive me if I sound dumb, I added your segment into my script but my logs output an error "NameError: name 'client' is not defined". Any solution?

Comment: `client` is your `discord.Client()`. You might have used `bot = discord.Client()` instead. Basically whatever uses `send_message` is what you named your client.

Answer (score 2):

To delete without fetching message use [TextChannel.delete_messages](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=delete_message#discord.TextChannel.delete_messages) and construct a [snowflake](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=delete_message#discord.abc.Snowflake) using [discord.Object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=delete_message#discord.Object).

```py
await channel.delete_messages([discord.Object(id=message_id)])
```