# Python Discord bot delete users message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot in python3 (discord.py 1.3.3, discord 1.0.1) and I have a need to delete a user message, but I can't figure out how to call the coroutine properly.

I have looked at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348148/delete-messages-with-python-discord-bot) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597094/how-to-delete-a-specific-message-by-id-using-discord-py?rq=1), and tried reviewing the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-message) (and the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)) but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's what I'm testing with:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='deleteme', help='testing command for dev use')
async def deleteme(ctx):
    msg = ctx.message.id
    print(f'DEBUG: message id is {msg}')
    await msg.delete
    # await ctx.delete(msg, delay=None)  #nope
    # await ctx.delete_message(ctx.message)  #nope
    # await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)  #nope
    # await command.delete_message(ctx.message)  #nope
    # await discord.Client.delete_message(msg)  #nope
```

Running this returns the console debug message with an ID number, but the message isn't deleted. If I add a debug print line after `await msg.delete` it doesn't return. So this tells me where the script is hanging. That said, I still haven't been able to figure out what the proper command should be.

The bots server permissions include "manage messages"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to delete a message, you have to use the `discord.Message` object, for example, you would do:

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

The `delete()` coroutine is a method of `discord.Message`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.